# How to find the limit of $\frac{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)...(1-85x)-1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

I am struggling to find out how to correctly write the steps to solve the limit of this series:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}=\frac{(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)...(1-85x)-1}{x}$$

I know, that the result is -3655 and I also know why: Since the limit approaches zero, powers higher than $x^1$ will be zero, and elements without $x$ will cancel out $(1-1=0)$. Therefore, I only care about elements that have $x^1$, which can be simplified to
$$-x(1+2+3+4+...+85)$$
and that gives us the formula $n(n+1)/2$, hence the result. The $x$ will then cancel out with the one in the denominator, leaving me with $-3655$.

What I do not know is how to solve this problem properly, that is using proper steps and formation.

Can anyone provide any solutions or tips?

Comment: "I also know why". Please tell us.

Comment: Since the limit approaches zero, powers higher than x^1 will be zero, and elements without x will cancel out (1-1=0). Therefore, I only care about elements that have x^1, which can be simplified to -x(1+2+3+4+...+85) and that gives us the formula n(n+1)/2, hence the result. The x will then cancel out with the one in the denominator, leaving me with -3655.

Answer (score 4):

**FIRST METHOD :**

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x)=(1-x)(1-2x)(1-3x)...(1-85x)$$

What you want to calculate is
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-1}{x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}$$

By definition of the derivative, you deduce $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)-1}{x} = f'(0)$$

which can be calculated, if you are courageous.

**SECOND METHOD :**

The function $f$ is polynomial, and its constant coefficient is $1$. That means that you can write $f(x)=1+\sum_{k=1}^{85} a_k x^k$. Then you see that
$$\frac{f(x)-1}{x}  = \sum_{k=1}^{85} a_k x^{k-1}$$
so the limit when $x$ tends to $0$ is equal exactly to $a_1$, i.e. the coefficient of $x$ in the polynomial function $f$. It is easy to see that this coefficient is equal to
$$a_1=- \sum_{k=1}^{85} k = -3655$$

Comment: The "if you are courageous" bit would perhaps boil down to labelling $f_n(x)=(1-x)(1-2x)\cdots(1-nx)$ and using induction on $n$ to find $f'_n(0)$... then setting $n=85$...

Comment: @StinkingBishop I just wanted to point that I am not courageous enough to write down the calculation :) But one can also differentiate the product directly (the derivative of the product is the sum of the product where you differentiate each factor successively).

Comment: @TheSilverDoe No, it is much easier with logarithm .

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah This is the exact same thing.

Comment: The derivative of a sum is much easier than of a product.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Not really, and taking the $\ln$ can bring some trouble. Like the ones you have trying to determine the domain of your $g$ :)

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Not a problem, I was just trying to point the OP to the right direction if *they* feel courageous.

Answer (score -1):

With the same $ f(x) $ defined above and
$$g(x)=\ln(f(x))\;for \; x<\frac{1}{85}$$
we have

$$f'(x)=f(x)g'(x)$$
with
$$g'(x)=\frac{-1}{1-x}-\frac{2}{1-2x}-...-\frac{85}{1-85x}$$

thus

$$f'(0)=f(0)g'(0)=-1-2-...-85=-\frac{85\cdot86}{2}$$

Comment: Please precise the domain of $g$. It is obviously not the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I just aded that $g$ is defined for $x<1/85

Comment: @TheSilverDoe It is defined if $ 1-85x>0$

Comment: You edited quickly !

Comment: Yes, that seems correct